# AngularJS Doughnut is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to create a doughnut in AngularJS. [I have referred this link](https://devcenter.appery.io/tutorials/angularjs/drawing-charts-in-angularjs-apps-with-chart-js/)  I am not getting where i am going wrong as its not showing any errors in console log.Here is my code.
  [I have created plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jaXYdUw7VQoS26zxoPb?p=preview)
Please help me to solve the problem. 
here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-chart.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<form name='myform' ng-init="step = 1">

<div ng-show="step==1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"> <h3 class="zoomIn">I am</h3> </div>
<div ng-form='step1form'>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="polarData.data" labels="polarData.labels" legend="true">
</canvas>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>

<script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `chart.js` for the app.

#### app.js

You had:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
```

You need to include the `chart.js` model in order to be able to use the library.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate", "chart.js"]);
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LujW8EI3wHhO95ttYzEm?p=preview)

Comment: It supposed to be this in app.js file - var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate", "angular-chart"]); as i changed the line from angular.module('chart.js', []) to angular.module('angular-chart', []) in angular-chart.js file.